# How to know the cardinalities from SQL-DDL schema?

Tags: sql

My question is how to know from the SQL-DDL schema that a relation is one-to-one or many-to-many or one-to-many?

Thanks,

Comment: SQL Server or another? What tools are you using if not SSMS for SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

A one-to-one relation will have a primary key or unique constraint on both ends.

A one-to-many relation will have a primary key or unique constraint on only one of the two ends.

A many-to-many relation will have a third table with non-unique foreign keys to two other tables. (Which together will make up the primary key for that table.)

Comment: "one-to-one" could also mean "one-to-(zero-or-one)", just line "one-to-many" could also mean "one-to-(zero-or-many)". It's not possible to deduct that from the model

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have foreign keys to associate entities

- They will show a `1:x..y` relationships where x is 0 or 1, y is 1 to N
- On the table with the foreign key constraint:

  - x can't be determined from DDL. That is, enforcement of a mandatory child row can't be done easily. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29 for the notation
  - Unique on that column means y = 1
  - non-unique means y = N

A link table to implement N:N will have two such relationships

This can be seen in a database diagram that you can generate from in-built or 3rd party tools. Examples:

- SQL Server Management Studio
- MySQL workbench

Comment: I don't think the statement `NOT NULL means x = 1` is true. Because if you don't have a row in the "child" table you effectivily have a 1:0 relationship. A "true" 1:1 relationship (or 1:n with n>0) cannot be enforced with regular SQL constraints (at least I can't think of a way)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: true. Bad wording. I was basing this on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29. Updated

Answer (score 0):

You can't read it directly from the schema. However, if you assume that the schema author was *very* thorough at implementing referential integrity, you can make some deductions. For example:

- 1 : 0..1 == one table has a foreign key on the same column(s) as the primary key, and pointing to the primary key column(s) on the other table.
- 0..N : 0..N == a separate linking table that has a foreign key pointing to table 1, another foreign key pointing to table 2, and a primary key covering all columns in both foreign keys.
- 1 : 0..N == the only safe thing you can assume if none of the others are true and there is a foreign key pointing to another table.

NB: The same deductions can also be made if a foreign key pointed to a unique constraint instead of a primary key.

Comment: "*otherwise it has a minimum value of one*". That is not true. You can have a NOT NULL column and still have a "one-to-(zero-or-one)" (by not inserting a row into the related table)